# D3.js graph edge reversal not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to work with the tutorial on D3.js directed graphs here: http://bl.ocks.org/cjrd/6863459. What I wanted to do was add the functionality that when the user selected an edge and pressed the "B" key, it reverses the edge. The good news is I got it to work as planned. The bad news is I don't know why it works :)

Here is my code -

```
switch(d3.event.keyCode) {
   case consts.B_KEY:
   d3.event.preventDefault();
   if (selectedEdge){
    var sourceNode = selectedEdge["source"];
    var targetNode = selectedEdge["target"];
    //thisGraph.edges.splice(thisGraph.edges.indexOf(selectedEdge), 1);
    thisGraph.edges.push({source: targetNode, target: sourceNode});
    thisGraph.updateGraph();
  }
```

This is within the GraphCreator.prototype.svgKeyDown of the JS file. With this code in place, when I click on an edge and press B, it reverses. Note however that I didn't say any where to delete the original edge. So, I would expect to see a double arrowed edge appear with this code. In fact, when I did have the line which I would hope would delete the original edge (the commented line in the code), it simply gets rid of the edge instead of reversing it. So, why does my code work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code snippet you have posted shows nothing unusual.
May be there is some bug somewhere else in the code you have not shared.

I have made a button to recreate your issue:

```
  function change(){
    edges.splice(0,1)//remove the one link
    edges.push({source: nodes[0], target: nodes[1]});//add the new inverted link
    graph.updateGraph()//update the graph
  }
```

Everything works as expected.

Working fiddle [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WaQuBbfxeIVX9tTBZQ0N?p=preview)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I am not expert here. But i have done quite a bit of d3 coding. To draw the links i needs unique id. 
It is created via "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "L" + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;

so when reverse the link add again, it creates new id and adds one more link. but it will on the same link and same xy and coordinates. so it will look like one but two links may there.

Why it works, src and target is required to draw the link, but direction is no concern for d3, it will add link between the src and dst. It will work till you have a unique id for each link and number of links between the node is not problem.

If you provide full working code, it will more easy to comment.

Comment: Actually, if there were two edges, I would have seen an edge once I deleted the reversed edge produced by my code of my code. But, I see only one. My complete code has other unrelated modifications, so it would be best to consider the code in the link I pasted and adding the case segment in my code to the "switch(d3.event.keyCode)" function as one additional CASE.